# How to make ajax failures visible?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I use a small library to make ajax calls.  I want the function to throw an error if it is fed a url that does not exist.

Currently, it fails silently, and simply passes back undefined for the response text.  This makes general trouble shooting more difficult.

Is there an easy way to do this?

```
/**************************************************************************************************
AJAX
*/

    // specify type/url/callback in passed object
    Pub.ajax = function (config_ajax) {
        var xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();

        // get
        if (config_ajax.type === 'get') {
            xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        // post
        if (config_ajax.type === 'post') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(config_ajax.data);
        }

        // post for form_data
        if (config_ajax.type === 'multi') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(config_ajax.data);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Add an Error handler...?

Comment: The readyState property will not tell you if the url is invalid .. I think I can use `this.status !== 200`

Comment: So you are saying that readyState is 4 and the status is 200 for an invalid url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you can't use [jQuery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which has an .success and .error.

You may need to make this a little more robust depending on what your calling and exactly how the server responds.

```
if (this.status === 200) {
    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
} else if (console) {
    console.error("ajax call failed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
**************************************************************************************************
AJAX
*/

    // specify type/url/callback in passed object
    Pub.ajax = function (config_ajax) {
        var xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();

        // get
        if (config_ajax.type === 'get') {
            xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(null);
        }

        // post
        if (config_ajax.type === 'post') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(config_ajax.data);
        }

        // post for form_data
        if (config_ajax.type === 'multi') {
            xhr.open("POST", config_ajax.url, true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    config_ajax.callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(config_ajax.data);
        }
        // when the ready state changes check for success or failure
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
            {
                        //Success
                alert('success');
            }else{
                        //Failure
                alert('Failure');
            }
        }

    };
```